# How to merge/aggregate Open API specs from multiple apps in an automated way

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

The company I work for has a set of microservices that each focuses on a different business capability e.g. payments, transactions, accounts, etc.

We create Open API specs in Swagger Hub (API first design) for each business capability.

Our services are predominantly .NET Core applications running in Kubernetes and we use the [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) library to auto generate the Swagger UI from the yml spec (which we copy across manually from Swagger Hub). We've also discussed using .NET attributes to auto-generate the OASs from code, which I'll bring up again below.

Our public clients (native apps & web SPAs) consume multiple business capability APIs and it doesn't really seem optimal to give the public client developers (who are mostly outsourced) multiple OASs i.e. one per business capability. There's also multiple partnerships in the works and I don't think it would look professional to give them 15 different API specs... Ideally we'd have a single API spec for each specific type of consumer (e.g. "Product X public client API", and/or "Product X back-end integration API") that can be broken down into separate categories for each business capability e.g:

[image]

Also, some of the operations on a specific business capability might be for different consumers (e.g. public clients or back-end integrations). We could probably work this out by the security scheme (i.e. whether user tokens or M2M tokens are required):

If we continue with the current approach of defining API specs in Swagger Hub for each business capability, we'll need to create an additional aggregated (and partially duplicated) API specs targeted at specific consumers that we would need to continually update manually.

We *could* switch to defining the aggregated (consumer focused) APIs specs in Swagger Hub, but then we'll need a different way to generate Swagger UI in the microservice applications. Perhaps we could use the attribute based approach mentioned previously to generate the Swagger UI for microservices, but then there's no guarantee it will perfectly align with the aggregated OAS defined in Swagger Hub... before we rush head first down this path, the question is;

Is it possible and are there any tools to merge separate OASs in an automated or semi-automated way (ideally with some basic filtering capabilities i.e. to filter operations based on security tags) so that we don't need to maintain separate aggregated OASs manually? Alternatively, are there any other approaches to solving this problem in a more automated way?

Comment: Do you use same authorization token for all APIs?

Comment: User routs would have a user access token obtained via authentication flow (i.e. authorization code grant with PKCE). back-end routes would require M2M token obtained via client credential flow. A lot of routes are one or the other, but there's a few that would be accessible to both users & machines.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible and are there any tools to merge separate OASs in an automated or semi-automated way

You can use APIMatic's API spec merge feature to automatically [merge your specs](https://docs.apimatic.io/manage-apis/api-merging/#merging-two-api-specifications---a-basic-example) and then [transform](https://docs.apimatic.io/manage-apis/api-merging/#transforming-the-zipped-file) the merged output into OpenAPI's format. Here are the steps:

1. Structure your directory as follows:

```
dir\
  accounts\  
    openapi.json
  payments\
    openapi.json
  transactions\
    openapi.json
  APIMATIC-META.json
```

2. A minimalistic metadata configuration file `APIMATIC-META.json` can look like this to enable merging:

```
{
    "MergeConfiguration": {
        "MergedApiName": "Product X",
        "MergeApis": true,
        "MergeSettings": {
          "SkipCodeGenValidation": true
       }
    }
}
```

3. ZIP the directory, upload it and transform it via their website to OpenAPI v3 to get your merged output. Here is a link that provides step by step guide on uploading and performing a transformation manually through the website:  https://docs.apimatic.io/manage-apis/api-merging/#transforming-the-zipped-file. Since you are looking for automation, APIMatic has an API to achieve the same too: https://www.apimatic.io/docs/api#/http/api-endpoints/transformation/transform-via-file

> ideally with some basic filtering capabilities i.e. to filter operations based on security tags

An OAS API spec you provide in the directory can have a metadata configuration file provided next to it as well which can contain filtering options to take out certain operations. Please see detailed reference document on this here: https://docs.apimatic.io/manage-apis/apimatic-metadata/#filtering-out-parts-of-api-definition-with-metadata
So, your directory structure can then look like the following:

```
dir\
  accounts\  
    openapi.json
    APIMATIC-META.json
  payments\
    openapi.json
    APIMATIC-META.json
  transactions\
    openapi.json
    APIMATIC-META.json
  APIMATIC-META.json
```

The inner metadata files can have a configuration like the following:

```
{
  "KeepEndpointsWithTags": ["public"]
}
```

When you ZIP the directory, upload and transform it, the output OAS would be the merged output of your "filtered" input OAS files. Note, however, that this filtering isn't based on security level information. It is based on the tags configured at operation level.